# Retrieving the contents of a post curl request in PHP

Tags: php, curl

An external API will send a curl post request to my php script similar to to this one:

```
$params=['productId'=>'123abc', 'quantity'=>100];
        $defaults = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://my-url/test.php',
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, ($defaults));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

How would I retrieve the productId and quantity in my php file? I've tried:

```
error_log('result $_POST ' . json_encode($_POST));
```

and

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
error_log('result $post ' .json_encode($post));
```

They log an empty string and empty array respectivly.

Comment: Ok, start by echoing out the returned string i.e. `echo $result;` then you/we can see what we are actually dealing with, and the penny may drop for you

Comment: @RiggsFolly client says : An external API will send a curl post request to my PHP script

Comment: in `test.php` file, try to do this `<?php print_r($_POST); print_r($_REQUEST);` and see what output you get